# Auto Schema change in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2008, schema

Why does Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 automatically change the Schema for an SSRS report from 2008 to 2010? When certain features are added (which are all 2008 compatible) the Schema is automatically changed from:

```
<Reportxmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

to:

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

Is there a way to force the Schema to remain as the 2008 version?

Please note that the TargetServerVersoin project property is set to SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Why do you want it to stay the same? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188874/ssrs-2014-report-deploy-issue) for why it happens for later versions and how to work around it. 2008 pre R2 is another version of the xmlns.

Comment: @SMM thanks for the response. We have our own software with embedded reports which is only capable of using 2008 schema.

Comment: If you just need the RDLs to be properly formatted for use then you should be able to set the target SSRS reports version in project properties and when you build you will get the appropriate xlnms versions in the bin folder. I don't think you can stop VS from doing that because at certain VS version levels, the native xmlns changes.

Comment: @SMM - Unfortunately the rdls in the bin folder are also in the 2010 schema, even with the project properties set to SQL 2008 R2. I only need the rdl file for upload into our software.

Comment: I don't have an old version of VS to check but did you try SQL 2008 instead of 2008 R2? My VS 2015 has 3 options representing the 3 variants of xmlns: 2008, 2008 R2 through 2014, and 2016+.

Comment: @SMM - Turns out I was using VS 2008 R2, which changes the schema for some reason. I have been advised that VS 2008 will not do the same. Lets hope so!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to stop it as far as I can tell, and VS2015 still behaves this way.

However, if you use the built-in publish, or run a build and use the `.rdl` files from `bin/` instead of your source folder then you will find that the reports have been modified to match the target version and will upload correctly.

More info: [SSRS 2014 report deploy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39188874/10245)