# Deploy RDLs from VS2013 to Sql 2008 ReportServer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have an `SSRS` project that was created in `VS2008` with several reports. These reports are deployed to `ReportServer for`Sql Server 2008` in a remote server.

After receiving the `VS2013` compatibility warning in my workstation, I successfully opened the `SSRS` project in `VS2013` and opened an RDL.

With that said, let's say I modify the RDL, what are my options to deploy this new report to the `ReportServer in`Sql Server 2008`?

I also have the `SQL Server 2012` MSDN media. Would updating `SQL 2008` to `SQL 2012` help in any way?

Edit:

Out of curiosity, I created a new report within the SSRS project and deployed the report (from my VS2013) to the remote server (with Sql 2008). It worked. I was under the impression that this wasn't possible. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS 2014 report deploy issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188874/ssrs-2014-report-deploy-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Under project properties you can have up to 3 options for TargetServerVersion depending on VS version and SSDT-BI version installed:

- SQL 2008
- SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2012, SQL 2014
- SQL 2016+ (new in VS 2015 with latest SSDT-BI)

Each of these uses a different xmlns in the report XML code. As you open each report your source report .rdl file will be upgraded to the latest xmlns - like it or not.

However when you deploy or build, the .rdl files in your bin folder will be compiled to match the target. As long as you use the bin folder versions (automatic with VS deploy) you can successfully deploy these to your server.

Comment: I have copied the information in this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188874/ssrs-2014-report-deploy-issue) and flagged this as a duplicate.