# SQL Server reporting services Downgrade

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I currently use Visual Studio 2015 with reporting services version 13.0.1700.281. However, this is out of line with the others in my company. Therefore I could do with downgrading my version to 2012 however, i cannot find any resources instructing how to do this.

Does anybody have any ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks,

Comment: I haven't tried but I think you have to use the correct version of SSDT with each version of Visual Studio. If you want to use VS 2015 you have to use the latest SSDT version. If you want to keep using VS 2015 but build reports for older version of SQL see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188874/ssrs-2014-report-deploy-issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the Reference Manager in the Assemblies Extensions tab. If installed, you can select different versions. You may need to change the version number - depending on the project type - in the web.config or app.config.

[image]

Do you mean the SQL server service (SSRS) itself, then I think that is only possible by installing of an older SQL Server version.