# How can we edit RDL made on Visual Studio 2015 to the lower version of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2016

I have made a SSRS Report on Visual Studio 2015, So is there is some way that I can open it on Visual Studio 2012 or else. I tried  to change the year on  URL path of SSRS code but that too didn't worked for me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: I don't know about this specific version, but between other versions the new one is putting in XML tags the earlier one doesn't know about. I don't know of a comprehensive list. Removing the tags can be a bit hit or miss, not sure it's worth the time.

Comment: Does the information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39192968/6490059) help at all?