# SSRS report migration from older to newer version

Tags: reporting-services

I have to migrate SSRS report(.RDL files) which were created on visual studio 2008r2  to SSDT 2013.

Is it possible? Could any one share the comments and details?

Thanks

Raj.

Comment: Just open them in the VS with the new SSDT installed and they should upgrade by them selves.

Comment: See some notes about what happens to the code when you do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39192968/6490059).

Comment: ^- I can confirm this also works with the Report Builder tool.