# Report Viewer in Visual Studio 2017: strange behavior

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, rdlc, report-viewer2016

I have old projects that use `ReportViewer` with the following schemas;

`xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"` and `mlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"`

Now I'm using VS 2017.
I have installed the `Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio` through Extensions and Update, so, when I open a rdlc that was created on `2008/01/reportdefinition` it works fine and I can modify it without problem.

However if I open a rdlc created on `2010/01/reportdefinition` the report designer request me convert the rdlc to the newer version of: `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition"`

Can someone explain why this happens? And how I can get the `2010/01` version to behave like the `2008/01` rather than force me to upgrade.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39192968/6490059).