# Migration of SSRS reports from 2008R2 to 2014 new environment

Tags: reporting-services

Hi I am having basic knowledge on SSRS and its been long time I worked on it. I am going to **migrate SSRS 2008R2 reports to SSRS 2014 server**.
So is that possible to transfer all existing reports without migrating database, connecting old database from SSRS reporting configuration service 2014?
If possible do I need to create new **reportserver** Database in the Old database because I am unable to connect to the existing **reportserver** database in the old DB from configuration services 2014?

Comment: Your client tools need to have support for the target version of SSRS. You can install the client tools for 2014 along side 2008 and connect to both instances using the proper client version. Does this answer what you are asking?

Comment: Hi Ross can you please elaborate more. Actually 2008R2 is in Server A and 2014 is in server B. So how can I configure?

Comment: Do you have a report solution containing all the reports that you are migrating to 2014? Are you trying to automate the migration yourself?

Comment: yes I am having the report solution in 2008R2 version and deployed in 2008R2 configuration services in native mode report server database.

Comment: Now my requirement is to publish existing reports from different server and higher version by connecting to same existing 2008R2 database

Comment: Ok, I thought you were in a migration to 2014. If you have some servers on 2008 and some on 2014 then I would suggest that you stick to the 2008 version of your client tools until all boxes are migrated. You can't deploy to 2008 if your client tools are 2014. However, you can install 2014 and 2008 client tools side by side. By the way, I have never heard of anyone setting up the ssrs services to run in a different version from the database as you are suggesting. I guess it can be done, however, I would be surprised if you do not run into some issues.

Comment: @RossBush - you can deploy with newer tools to older versions. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39192968/6490059).

Comment: I would use caution on this. I doubt you can just target the endpoint and deploy at will without issue. There is no guarantee that the new version(s) will not have breaking changes.